# Why is the code asking to catch IOException

Tags: java, exception

I amwriting a program using try catch but the code is asking to surround InputStreamReader  and BufferedReader with try-catch to catch IOException or declare IOException using throws. But why is it asking to do so when I am using catch to the IOException.

## Here is the code:

```
public class BufferedReader3 {


    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        InputStreamReader  r=null;
        BufferedReader br=null;
        String name="";    





        try 
        {
            r =new InputStreamReader(System.in);    
            br =new BufferedReader(r); 

            while(!name.equals("stop"))
            {    

                System.out.println("Enter data: ");   
                name=br.readLine();
            } 



            System.out.println("data is: "+name);    


        }              
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        finally
        {

            br.close();    
            r.close();    
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `.close()` methods also throws `IOException` and you are not handling them

Comment: Hint: use `try-with-resources`.

Comment: Both `br.close()` and `r.close()` can throw `IOException`s, `finally` is not part of the `try-catch` part of the code, so they don't get included, you have to handle them separately. In fact, Java now includes a feature to do this for you, see [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

in `finally` block `close()` calls can also throw `IOException`. So the compiler complains about that because `IOException` is of type `Checked Exception` you should also handle this case.

let's try to handle this with;

1. make use of `try with resources`

   ```
   String name = "";
   try ( InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in); 
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r); ){

       while (!name.equals("stop")) {
           System.out.println("Enter data: ");
           name = br.readLine();
       }
       System.out.println("data is: " + name);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
2. another `try catch` block in `finally`

   ```
   InputStreamReader r = null;
   BufferedReader br = null;
   String name = "";

   try {
       r = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       br = new BufferedReader(r);
       while (!name.equals("stop")) {
           System.out.println("Enter data: ");
           name = br.readLine();
       }

       System.out.println("data is: " + name);

   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   finally {
       try {
           br.close();
           r.close();
       } catch (IOException e2) {
           e2.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```
3. make use of deprecated `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(Closeable ...)`

   ```
   InputStreamReader r = null;
   BufferedReader br = null;
   String name = "";

   try {
       r = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       br = new BufferedReader(r);
       while (!name.equals("stop")) {
           System.out.println("Enter data: ");
           name = br.readLine();
       }

       System.out.println("data is: " + name);

   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   finally {
       IOUtils.closeQuietly(br, r);
   }
   ```

Comment: But if instead of BufferedReader I use Scanner then in finally bliock close() method does not ask to catch IOException. Why?